# Using grep() or sub() on sequence objects?

Tags: r, regex, traminer

I want to summarize certain patterns in an event sequence object. The reason I want to do this is that my sequences are too long (several hundred events) and this makes computation extremely difficult. I have identified frequent subsequences, and now I want to replace certain frequent subsequences with markers that denote a full subsequence (as if it were a single event).

For example, I may have a pattern that I want to replace, say FA-FA. In the sequence

```
FA-FA-EX-EX-FA (5 event markers)
```

this would now be:

```
FAFA_pattern-EX-EX-FA (4 event markers)
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal.tse)
actcal.seqe <- seqecreate(id = actcal.tse$id, 
timestamp = actcal.tse$time, event = actcal.tse$event)
actcal.seqe2 <- sub("(LowPartTime)-1-(Stop)", "replaced_pattern", actcal.seqe)
```

this seems to work fine, however, it converts the sequence into a text string, and it no longer functions as a sequence object. Is there a way to conduct such replacement operations while maintaining the sequence object's status as a sequence object?

Comment: I think you need to learn more about the event sequence class and how to convert from and to character vectors. If you can write a character vector and coerce it to an event sequence object then you've done this.

Comment: Although not necessary I find the convenience functions in stringr makes regex tasks much more straightforward